# how to add class to jquery.datatables columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I made a large table for jquery.datatables which is works great for me.
but i need a class name set to each td element relative to its column.
fo example i want a column (including th and all td's) have a `class="volume"`.
there is this issues:
 i use this code to initialize the class but it is not working.

```
"aoColumnsDefs": [
    { "sClass": "volume", "aTargets": [2] }
]
```

**EDIT:**
my table is created and refeshes dynamically. and it is made of a js-array which i prefer not to touch it ie. just to add class names
**EDIT:**
iuse this code to itialize my table:

```
$('#dataTable').dataTable({
    "aaData": dataCnt,
    "aoColumnsDefs": [
        { "sClass": "volume", "aTargets": [2] }
    ],
    "aoColumns": columnsHd,
    "bStateSave": true,//saving status in coockie
    "iCookieDuration": 10,//coockie life duration in seconds
    "sScrollX": "100%",
    "sScrollY": (winHei-200),
    "sDom": '<"H"RCfrl>t<p"F"i>',
    "oColVis": {
        "buttonText": "&nbsp;",
        "bRestore": true,
        "sAlign": "left"
    },
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
});
```

i hope it helps
  **EIDT: **
`columnsHd` is an array which is created dynamicaly from my json headers and now is exactly:

```
[
{ "sTitle": "macaddr" },
{ "sTitle": "lat" },
{ "sTitle": "ip" },
{ "sTitle": "clientname" },
{ "sTitle": "relay0mask" },
{ "sTitle": "relay0stat" },
{ "sTitle": "relay1stat" },
{ "sTitle": "clientid" },
{ "sTitle": "bldname" },
{ "sTitle": "uptime" },
{ "sTitle": "current" },
{ "sTitle": "temperature" },
{ "sTitle": "softver" },
{ "sTitle": "volume" },
{ "sTitle": "hardver" },
{ "sTitle": "relay1mask" },
{ "sTitle": "pic" },
{ "sTitle": "comment" },
{ "sTitle": "lon" },
{ "sTitle": "rtt" },
{ "sTitle": "bldaddr" },
 ]
```

Comment: have you tried templates or dynamically generating your "table"? what exactly is your goal? adding a class tag to a html-column?

Comment: You aware that its being add to the third column ?

Comment: yes i know it uses a zero based indexing but i tried any combinations and it just did not worked. i don know where do i do this wrong

Comment: are you sure that the class in not being applied to your `td`? have you checked with browser dev tools ?

Comment: i checked it with dev tools in chrome/ IE/ FF and clean refreshed it. even restart my server and system to check it. it did not worked @daniel

Comment: it should work , what version of datatbles are you using ? , try `"aoColumns" : [   
        null, null   
        { sClass: "volume" }  
    ] `

Comment: thank u @daniel for your responses. i use 1.9.4 and i edited my post with my initilization code if it helps?

Comment: my guess is that `"aoColumns": columnsHd, overrides the "aoColumnsDefs": [ { "sClass": "volume", "aTargets": [2] } , ],`

try to replace their order in code
or just add the class directly in `"aoColumns": columnsHd,`
like this `sClass: "volume"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My guess is that `"aoColumns": columnsHd, overrides the "aoColumnsDefs": [ { "sClass": "volume", "aTargets": [2] } , ],`

Try to replace their order in code

Or just add the class directly in `"aoColumns": columnsHd,`
like this `"sClass": "volume"`

complete code :

try changing `{ "sTitle": "ip" },` into `{ "sTitle": "ip", "sClass": "volume" },`

and remove the

```
"aoColumnsDefs": [
    { "sClass": "volume", "aTargets": [2] }
],
```

---

Note that in datatables 1.10 you should use [aoColumnDefs](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns)

Comment: i have changed their order => not working. i changed `"aoColumns": columnsHd, like this sClass: "volume"` => whole table not working actually not generates

Comment: try changing `{ "sTitle": "ip" },` into `{ "sTitle": "ip", "sClass": "volume" },` and remove the `"aoColumnsDefs": [
        { "sClass": "volume", "aTargets": [2] } , 
    ],` I guess it didn't work before cause I forgot to add `"` before and after the `sClass`

Comment: its `"aoColumnDefs"` without the extra s. http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns

Answer (score 1):

The answer for the question is

```
"aoColumnsDefs": [
    { "sClass": "classname", "aTargets": [whatever target you want to apply] }
]
```

to use other options: (ref [datatable](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns))

[image]