# Adding a name to TD (columns) in DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to add names to each `td` in table. Like this.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td name="Name">#Value#</td>
            <td name="Type">#Value#</td>
            <td name="Price">#Value#</td>
        </tr>
        ....
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So generally I want all columns to have names.
This is what I browsed through and still can't really "put my finger" on it.
[DataTables forum post](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/34602), 
[how to add class to jquery.datatables columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231660/how-to-add-class-to-jquery-datatables-columns)

Comment: Could you please explain clearly, what you want to do?

Comment: I clearly explained it. I want to add a name to a TD with DataTables plugin.

Comment: @rexdefuror Whatever you are trying to achieve can be done by assigning `id` to your columns or you can assign `id` to your table. Is it feasible for your solution?

Comment: Unfortunately it HAS to be `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Assign Id to your `td` fetch that and assign it name attribute .

```
 <tr>
     <td id="tdFirst" >#Value#</td>

 </tr>

 var nTds = $('#tdFirst').attr('name', "WhateverNameYouWant");
```

It's not a very good solution but see if it works for you.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that as well, but trying to find some more eligible solution if possible. Thanks though.

Comment: @rexdefuror If your columns and their names are constant throughout whole table (or rows), You can select whole table and loop through it assigning names using this http://api.jquery.com/eq/